# use of 'until' with 'foreach()' in scala to avoid for loops

Tags: scala

```
(1 until Dimensions).foreach(x=>(x,r.nextInt))
```

I want to avoid use of for loops. what i want is a a List such that List[(Int,Int)]
and values should be such that:

```
List((1,9),(2,57),(3,78))
```

the first sub element of each element represents the index and second element represents a random Integer.
The above piece of code  is giving returning () without toList and with toList is giving error.
what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` returns `Unit` (i.e. nothing) so it's not valid to do that. You should use a `map`:

```
(1 until Dimensions).map(x=>(x,r.nextInt))
```

From the List [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html):

> `final def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit`
>
> [use case] Applies a function `f` to all elements of this list.

---

> `final def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]`
>
> [use case] Builds a new collection by applying a function to all
> elements of this list.